# python SSL recv raises a Memory Error

Tags: python, ssl

Using the following code to receive data:

```
    socket_ssl = ssl.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET))
    socket_ssl.connect((address, 443))

    data = socket_ssl.recv(4)
    size = process(data)
    buff = socket_ssl.recv(size)
    while len(buff) < size :
        buff += socket_ssl.recv(size)
    return buff
```

That code works most of the time, but sometimes fails, python raises a Memory Error:

```
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 341, in recv
    return self.read(buflen)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/ssl.py", line 260, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len)
MemoryError
```

I noticed it fails when `size` is "big", bigger than 1Mo. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Simply use a size for recv which is not too big. ssl recv will only return up to the size of a single SSL frame anyway, i.e. 16k.  Apart from that you might clean up your code example which sometimes uses `socket_ssl` and sometimes `s_ssl` for the same (I guess so) socket

Comment: Thanks as simple as it seemed, that worked, I fixed my naming issues too.